# Laravel 5.2: How to customize default auth table name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.2, and i want to customize the default 'users' table name.
i found a multiple replies for this question, so by testing all, it doesn't work:
by changing `/App/config/Auth.php` file, by adding `'table' => 'members'`, and finaly renaming table name on the `/database/migrations` folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly i found the solution,
firstly, you have to edit the **2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php**:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password', 60);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}
```

and change, `users` to `members`.

Then you run **artisan migrate** command.

Now, add `protected $table = 'members';` in your **app/User** model. and in **App/config/Auth.php** file, add `'table' => 'members',` in **User Providers** section, so it become:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'members',
    ],
],
```

Finaly, for the validation rule in **app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php** file, edit the validator method, so it become:

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:members',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}
```

So that we replace `unique:users` to `unique:members`. and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this in `User` model:

```
protected $table = 'users';
```

to this:

```
protected $table = 'members';
```

Also, change table name inside `config\auth.php`

Also, clear all cache after these changes.

Comment: I keep receiving an error message: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'telestruct.users' doesn't exist

Comment: Try to trace the error to find out what exactly causes it, because I can't see hardcoded `users` table anywhere else in 5,2,29,